# How to specify precision and scale in a rails migration generation command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, decimal, scale, precision

When generating migrations via the command line you can specify the type of field you want to create. In the case of decimals this would give

```
rails generate migration AddAmountToOrder amount:decimal
```

This way you get a migration with a decimal column for your database. But you have to manually go to the file and add values for precision and scale like this

```
t.decimal :amount  # generated, but...
t.decimal :amount, precision: 10, scale: 2  # ... wanted!
```

How can you supply these values via the command line so that you can immediately do a `rake db:migrate` without first adding precision and scale to the migration file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can specify `precision` and `scale` in your migration generator command as follows:

```
rails generate migration AddAmountToOrder amount:decimal{10.2}
#precision: 10, scale: 2
```

Comment: where is this documented please?